# Try to solve root in inequality got wrong result

Tags: inequality, roots

I am very confused. So I have to solve this [inequality](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%28-5/24%29%5E2%2b1/4%29). The result is $13/24$.

But if I try to solve it myself, I get $17/24$. Because:

$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{-5}{24}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{4}} = \frac{5}{24} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{24} + \frac{12}{24} = \frac{17}{24}.$$

The right solution should be $13/24$.
Where is my failure?

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ne a+b$

Comment: You’re not solving an inequality: you’re simplifying the expression with the square root.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's right. It was a part of my inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sqrt{(-5/24)^2+1/4} = \sqrt{25/24^2+1/4} = \sqrt{(25+6\cdot 24)/24^2} = \sqrt{169}/\sqrt{24^2} = 13/24$

Comment: Okay, at first I have to do the addition under the root and THEN I can solve it. Right?

Comment: @bobmorane, that's right. the trick is to get it into the form $\sqrt{a^2}/\sqrt{b^2} = a/b$

Comment: Thank you all, now I got it.